# Are Bitmap Fields Containing Only One 1 Appropriate for K-Modes Hamming Distance

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, dataset, algorithms, mixed-type-data

I have a dataset with mixed datatypes:

```
id    amount    creator    accounts
1     100       jane       cash
1     100       jane       accounts receivable
2     200       john       tax account
```

Each `id` can have only one creator. Each `id` can have one or more accounts. For the accounts data, I am one hot encoding the accounts and then joining them into a bitmap:

```
id    amount    creator    accounts
1     100       jane       110
2     200       john       001
```

My plan was to apply k-prototypes to the resulting dataset. K-prototypes uses k-modes and the Hamming (# of replacements) distance to calculate similarity between categorical features and the modes. I think this works well for the bitmaps with multiple 1s. However, Hamming distance does not make sense for `creator`, because my assumption is that people are not more similar just because they have similar names. Therefore, I need to one hot encode the creator feature as well.

After one hot encoding, does it make sense to combine the creator features into a bitmap like the accounts? Each `id` can only have creator, so the bitmaps would only have replacement counts of 0 or 1.

Alternatively, am I overthinking this? Should k-modes actually be applied directly to single-value categorical variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-modes should directly on the categorical data, not on a one-hot encoding. John != Jane != Mary. Otherwise, the mode will usually be 0, and your prototypes are all 0.

But if you do not expect the creator attribute to be important, then do not use it.

Comment: So as long as it's a single-value categorical feature, just apply k-modes directly? Let's say the names are John, Joan, and Mary. Wouldn't John and Joan be deemed more similar (1 substitution) than John and Mary (4 substitutions)?

Comment: No. That would require transforming the labels to a byte array of a fixed length, and for string editing you'd use Levenshtein instead of Hamming and not kmodes. John != Jane. 1 column different: the name column. Only John = John is no difference.

Comment: Thank you very much - that makes sense. The bitmap makes sense for the accounts feature though, right? Since there are multiple possible values, the bitmap seems like it simply creates one string that is a representation of all the strings.

Comment: This: http://rosalind.info/glossary/hamming-distance/ seems to oppose your description, but I could be missing something

Comment: To add more detail - it seems like Hamming Distance requires strings of the same length, and the similarity measure is based on substitutions of symbols (i.e. letters).

Comment: If you define symbols to be characters, yes. If each *column* value is one symbol, then you get the version used with kmodes, where you only need to have the same columns. It's more powerful: you can trivially store each character in a column.

Comment: Some people prefer the same "simple matching distance". But in essence, it's still Hamming distance. And Wikipedia again only discusses the binary case.

Comment: that makes sense! so the bitmaps for the multi-value categorical (accounts)...are those helping the way I think they are? Or will k-modes just look at each bitmap as a whole and just be != or =?

Comment: Depends on your code. But I'd expect it to use equality, not bit operations. In particular for the mode. But if you think through what the mode is, chances are that the mode always is 0. I don't think kmodes is appropriate for your data.

Comment: When would k-modes be applicable then? If it's always equal or not equal, then the mode would generally be 0...regardless of what the data looks like.

Comment: When you have many columns with multi-valued preferences, and expect clusters that e.g. have favorite color blue, red, and yellow respectively. The mode is the most frequent value; but if you have a dominant/default/missing value that is likely to always be the mode. For example, a 'state' attribute is likely good if you have users from all over the US, but if 90% of your users are in California, likely all modes will be 'CA' and the attribute is effectively ignored.

Comment: Starting to make more sense...so for the account data, should that actually be unpivoted so that there is one account in each record and, therefore, multiple records for each id? Or just leave it with comma separated strings, but don't convert it to a bitmap?